# Removing Rows with Reversed Values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with the following values in columns A and B:

```
**A  |   B**

1  |   2
2  |   1
3  |   4
4  |   3
```

And I only want:

```
1  |   2
3  |   4
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what order are you returning the rows? In terms of your order, you can use;

```
SELECT X.* FROM MYTABLE X
LEFT JOIN MYTABLE Y ON X.A = Y.B AND X.B = Y.A
WHERE X.A < X.B
```

or

```
SELECT X.* FROM MYTABLE X
LEFT JOIN MYTABLE Y ON X.A = Y.B AND X.B = Y.A
WHERE X.rowid < Y.rowid
```

Comment: These are going to fail if some of the rows are singletons.

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove all rows that have duplicates, i.e., all rows for which a duplicate row exists:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM MyTable AS T2
              WHERE T2.A = MyTable.B
                AND T2.B = MyTable.A
                AND A < B)
```

(The `A < B` ensures that only one of the two duplicate rows gets removed.)

Comment: Thanks, I just chose the other one because it was in standard select, from, where query form, and I didn't want to have to use the Delete function.